# How to handle NSJSONSerialization's crashing when disconnected to internet

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services, nsjsonserialization

I implement web service in my app. My way is typical.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//Web Service  xxx,yyy are not true data
    NSString *urlString =   @"http://xxx.byethost17.com/yyy";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    dispatch_async(kBackGroudQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveLatest:)     withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });   
    return YES;
}

- (void)receiveLatest:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
    NSString *Draw_539 = [json objectForKey:@"Draw_539"];
....
```

console error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

When my iphone has connection to Internet, the app works successfully. But if it disconnects to Internet, app will crash on `NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];`
Can you show me how to handle this error? Is `NSError` helpful?

Comment: The error is telling you that "responseData" is nil.  The way to avoid the exception is to test "responseData" and not invoke JSONObjectWithData if it's nil.  Instead react however you feel you should for this error condition.

Comment: try/catch, or see if error is an error.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, I add if statement `if(responseData)`. Then when responseData is nil , JSONObjectWithData won't be invoked. I think my question is common and entry-level, but I can't find information on the web.

Comment: The thing you're lacking is skills at reading error messages -- invest a little time/effort at improving there.  The error message was telling you that "data parameter is nil", which clearly was referring to the parameter of JSONObjectWithData.  And that would logically be nil if the internet connection failed while transferring.  This is the sort of thing you need to learn how to figure out, if you want to be a programmer.

Comment: @HotLicks Now my problem is solved but no one "answer my question" below.

Comment: I suggest `AFNetworking` framework. Much better than manually handling all these basic tasks.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen  Thank you. Could you teach me more about `AFNetworking ` in my case?

Comment: `AFNetworking` handles JSON parsing internally, so you don't need to parse it yourself. In case Internet is down, it won't try to parse the  response, but instead invoking a failure block. It also handles the async queue for you. There are fairly good documentation / sample projects on [github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: The best way to avoid an error like this would be to use Tony Million's "Reachability" class. and if there's no connection bypass the method. Also you really should be checking your data anyway in the case of other Errors and handle them accordingly.  https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is telling you that "responseData" is nil. The way to avoid the exception is to test "responseData" and not invoke JSONObjectWithData if it's nil. Instead react however you feel you should for this error condition.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to gracefully check if "responseData" is nil?

Answer (score 9):

You are not checking if your `responseData` is nil or not, before passing it to the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method.

Probably you should try this:

```
- (void)receiveLatest:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    if(responseData != nil)
    {
         NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
         NSString *Draw_539 = [json objectForKey:@"Draw_539"];
    }
    else
    {
         //Handle error or alert user here
    }
    ....
}
```

**EDIT-1:** For good practice, you should check this `error` object after `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method to check and see if JSON data is successfully converted to NSDictionary or not

```
- (void)receiveLatest:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    if(responseData != nil)
    {
         NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
         if(!error)
         {
              NSString *Draw_539 = [json objectForKey:@"Draw_539"];
         }
         else
         {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
              //Do additional data manipulation or handling work here.
         } 
    }
    else
    {
         //Handle error or alert user here
    }
    ....
}
```